# Is it possible to slice a video file blob and then re-encode it server side?

Tags: react-native, blob, expo, video-encoding

Been absolutely banging my head on this one and I would like a sanity check. Mainly if what I want to do it's even possible as I am severely constrained by react-native which has pretty dodgy Blob support.

We all know that video encoding is expensive, thus instead of forcing the user to encode using ffmpeg I would like to delegate the whole process to the backend. It's all good, except that sometimes you might want to trim 30s of a video and it's pointless to upload 3+ minutes of it.

So I had this idea of slicing the blob of the video file:

```
  const startOffset = (startTime * blobSize) / duration;
  const endOffset = (endTime * blobSize) / duration;
  const slicedBlob = blob.slice(startOffset, endOffset);
  // Setting the type as third option is ignored
```

Something like this, the problem is that the file becomes totally unreadable once it reaches the backend.
React Native cannot handle Blob uploads, thus they are converted in base64, which is totally fine for the whole video, but not for the sliced blob.

This even if I keep the beginning intact:

```
  const slicedBlob = blob.slice(0, endOffset);
```

I feel like the reason is that the file becomes a application/octet-stream  which might impact the decoding?

I am at a bit of a loss here as I cannot understand if this is a react native issue with blobs or if it simply cannot be done.

Thanks for any input.

p.s. I prefer to stick to vanilla expo without using external libraries, I am aware that one exists to handle blobs, but not keen on ejecting relying on external libraries if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply cut of chunks of a file and have it readable on the other side. For example, in an mp4 the video resolution is only stored in one place. If those bytes get removed, the decoder has no idea how to decode the video.

Yes it is possible to repackage the video client side by rewriting the container, and dropping full GOPs. But it’s would be about 1000 lines for code for you to write and would be limited to certain codecs and containers.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it was the case, it was good to double check.